# iPhone:Set imageView in transparent portion of the Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am making an application in which user will be allowed to select a photo frame firstly and after that he/she can have to select 2 photos from gallery for that photo frame (photo frame is an image which coontains two transparent holes in which we have to set the selected photos)and he/she can crop these image according to them.And after he/she is done with cropping a new view will get open with that selected photo frame and those two cropped images will be set in those two transparent whole. I have finished till the cropping is done.

## Question

How to set those two images in the transparent portion so that it will show properly in all the devices and the transparent portion keeps changing according to the photo frames the user will select. [image: These kind of photo frames i'm providing][image]

Comment: Is there any library or anything which can help me to achieve my task? Please help me i'm stuck in this problem since last 15 days. :(

Comment: above frame is PNG file right and middle heart portion is transparent  ?

Comment: Yes.And i want to set the user selected images from gallery into these transparent portions. @CodeChanger

Comment: Do we have the position and size data for transparent portion for each image?

Comment: Thats what i want to know.If we get the postion and size of the transparent portion then i we can put those two user selected images on that position by creating imageViews of the respective sizes @KrishnaCA

Comment: No thats not gonna work sorry but Thanx for your suggestion. @ravi.p

Comment: You need knowledge of image processing for this. You are supposed to read pixel data for each image and identify the position for white portion and then do your job. If you need help in this. Let me know

Comment: Is this the only way because i had tried this trick but it dint work first of all it takes a alot of time to read every pixel of the whole image..but still please let me know what is your way. @KrishnaCA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new image on view.
Add gesture to move and resize (zoom) new image, set perfect position for new image (i.e at centre of frame), Then send image view to back side of you main image view.
After that render both view, and make new image with UIGraphicsContext.

I have render code for you.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewCombineImages.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    self.viewCombineImages.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: But the flow of my app is such that just after im done with cropping of the two images they should get set automatically inside the frame..User shouldn't be allowed to interact further so i cant add gestures to the images right. @Sagar Chauhan

Comment: Ok, you are right about your way. But How will you know that where is transparent view position in your imageView, every time you can’t set it manually because images are different every time. @Abhijeet.

Comment: If you don’t want user interaction with image after cropping, then allow only move image to position. So user can set exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement here you can set 3 ImageView.

> 1. Image view with Person1 Image.
> 2. Image View with Person2 Image.
> 3. Image View with Frame Image.

so the stack of subview is like `UIViewController->UIView->Person Image View1, Person ImageView 2 -> Frame Image View`.

**Like this screenshot.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

And did not need transparent image position just do both image size half of the frame and set it below frame image view and you can achieve this like my screenshot.

Comment: This idea can work only for this frame..What if user selects another frames?? Then the transparent area's position will also change right? then this wont be working. @CodeChanger

Comment: In my opinion  all Frame size will be same than and than you can achieve this other wise its look wired with different different size.

Comment: In above 2 frame sample both size are same and that is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If above frame is .png file, it is possible to make transparent those parts. I thought you need three UIImageViews.

upper - decoration frame
under - person1's image view / person2's image view.

If user select two images, apply each picture on image view.
And adjust those size and coordinate. You can use

```
[person1ImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Also, you can rotate those by using

```
person1ImageView.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

Comment: But how can i get the x,y position and width and height of the transparent portion of the Png file above? @Lisa

Comment: Can anyone give me a proper answer related to my problem??