# How to cut a specific part from my CALayer

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a UIView. My UIView has a layer. I added another layer to it. I need to cut a circle in this layer when the user moves his finger to create a drawing effect. I will leave my code, but it is not correct, as it creates a circle once.

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
  private var recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

  private var maskLayer: CALayer!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
  }


  private func setup() {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeGesture))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds

    self.layer.insertSublayer(maskLayer, at: 0)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
  }

  private func crateMask(location: CGPoint, layer: CALayer) {
    let maskFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: location.x - 25 , y: location.y - 25 ), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

    layer.createMask(maskRect: maskFrame, invert: true)

  }

  @objc func swipeGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: self)
    print(location)
    crateMask(location: location, layer: self.maskLayer )
  }
}


extension CALayer {
  func createMask(maskRect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
    print(maskRect)
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let path = CGMutablePath()

    if (invert) {
        path.addRect(self.bounds)
    }

    let cornerRadius = maskRect.height / 2
    path.addRoundedRect(in: maskRect, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)

    maskLayer.path = path
    if (invert) {
        maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    }

    self.mask = maskLayer

  }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of the UI: https://prnt.sc/ozki6s
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478608/iphoneset-imageview-in-transparent-portion-of-the-image/41479427#41479427

Comment: I do not understand, how this can help me